# Pandas plot, vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

It was working perfectly earlier but for some reason now I am getting strange errors.

pandas version: `1.2.3`

matplotlib version: `3.7.0`

sample dataframe:

```
df
    cap       Date
0    1     2022-01-04
1    2     2022-01-06
2    3     2022-01-07
3    4     2022-01-08
```

```
df.plot(x='cap', y='Date')
plt.show()
```

```
df.dtypes
cap              int64
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

I get a traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py", line 955, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/__init__.py", line 61, in plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 279, in generate
    self._setup_subplots()
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_matplotlib/core.py", line 337, in _setup_subplots
    fig = self.plt.figure(figsize=self.figsize)
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/_api/deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 813, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 382, in new_figure_manager
    _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 360, in _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread
    if _get_required_interactive_framework(_get_backend_mod()):
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 208, in _get_backend_mod
    switch_backend(rcParams._get("backend"))
  File "/Volumes/coding/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 331, in switch_backend
    manager_pyplot_show = vars(manager_class).get("pyplot_show")
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

Comment: this seems like a bug in their implementation, they were assuming that `manager_class` has a `__dict__` attribute, but apparently, it possibly doesn't. This is they should have used `getattr(manager_class, "pyplot_show", None)` instead of `vars(manager_class).get("pyplot_show")`.

Comment: BUT Since you haven't actually provided a [mcve], it is impossible to say whether it is a bug in matplotlib or something you did. Since the code above runs if I create resonable values and imports... please **always** provide a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using the most recent matplotlib and pandas versions? Which matplotlib backend? Which environment?

Comment: @JohanC @juanpa.arrivillaga matplotlib version `matplotlib: 3.7.0`. pandas version: `1.2.3`

Comment: I also faced same error by simply calling ```plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])```

Comment: @tung changing the file as per juanpa.arrivillaga comment makes it work.

Comment: I was having the same problem when, on Python 3.9.5 and matplotlib 3.7.0 (outside jupyter environment). It was OK on matplotlib==3.5.0 though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In fact, this problem may be caused by running your code like default script (or in PyCharm interactive console), not in Jupyter.

If it is true, you can fix this error by setting up backend directly in your file with `use` function:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.use('TkAgg')  # !IMPORTANT

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
res = ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 2, 3])  # Plt some data on the axes.o
# plt.show() # optionally show the result.
```

In some cases `TkAgg` may not be available. When firstly check, which backend you use. for this, run this simple code:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
print(mpl.get_backend())
```

**BUT!** this must be run just by your hands in default terminal, outside of PyCharm. (e.g create simple `test.py` file, paste code, and run `python test.py`)

**Why?**  Because PyCharm (at least in scientific projects) runs all files with the interactive console, where backend `module://backend_interagg` is used. And this backend causes same error as you have.

So. add `mpl.use('TkAgg')` in the head of your file, or checkout which backend you can use and paste those names in this function.

Answer (score 4):

The solution by NEStenerus did not work for me, because I don't have tkinter installed and did not want to change my package configuration.

#### Alternative Fix

Instead, you can disable the **"show plots in tool window"** option, by going to
*Settings | Tools | Python Scientific | Show plots in tool window* and unchecking it.