# Can't plot pandas in matplotlib: TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot `alpha` versus `fluxes` in the pandas dataframe `all_fluxes`. Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
all_fluxes
Out[47]: 
      reaction    fluxes  alpha         Gene
0       CYTDK2  0.000000    0.0          MDH
1         XPPT  0.000000    0.0          MDH
2        HXPRT  0.000000    0.0          MDH
3        NDPK5  0.000000    0.0          MDH
4       SHK3Dr  0.312780    0.0          MDH
        ...       ...    ...          ...
2711    OCTNLL  0.000000    1.0          PHI
2712  EX_thf_c -0.000503    1.0          PHI
2713  EX_nad_c -0.001712    1.0          PHI
2714       HPS  0.000000    1.0          PHI
2715       PHI  0.000000    1.0          PHI
```

But when I call

```
all_fluxes.plot(x='alpha',y='fluxes')
```

this is what I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3460, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-46-cac32768086e>", line 1, in <module>
    all_fluxes.plot(x='alpha',y='fluxes')
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1000, in __call__
    return plot_backend.plot(data, kind=kind, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\__init__.py", line 71, in plot
    plot_obj.generate()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 451, in generate
    self._setup_subplots()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_matplotlib\core.py", line 512, in _setup_subplots
    fig = self.plt.figure(figsize=self.figsize)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 813, in figure
    manager = new_figure_manager(
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 382, in new_figure_manager
    _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread()
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 360, in _warn_if_gui_out_of_main_thread
    if _get_required_interactive_framework(_get_backend_mod()):
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 208, in _get_backend_mod
    switch_backend(rcParams._get("backend"))
  File "C:\Users\MyName\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 331, in switch_backend
    manager_pyplot_show = vars(manager_class).get("pyplot_show")
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_utils.py:606: FutureWarning: iteritems is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use .items instead.
  for item in s.iteritems():
```

Comment: This is not reproducible with what you've shared. What you have shared is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (you only shared a single line of code and a small portion of a data frame).

Comment: Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75453995/pandas-plot-vars-argument-must-have-dict-attribute) which seems to be talking about the issue you face